# маску на два инпута для ввода телефона

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, inputmask

Вот макет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот HTML

```
   <div class="tel_inputs_wrapp">
        <p>+7</p>
        <div class="input_1">
            <p>(</p>
            <input type="number" alt="" placeholder="" />
            <p>)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input_2">
            <input type="number" alt="" placeholder="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Сверстать макет можно как пожелаете, главное чтобы было похоже. Нужно чтобы при вводе трех цифр в первый инпут тот что в скобках курсор автоматически переходил на следующий инпут еще для 7 цифр. Как такую маску сделать?

Comment: Вот хорошая библиотека по работе с масками https://github.com/uNmAnNeR/imaskjs

Comment: Воспользуйтесь плгином jquery masked input

Answer (score 0):

Записал на четырех инпутах... Наверно можно было бы покороче, но тут оно тупо берет и проверяет количество введенных символов при вводе. Если кол-во оказывается больше, чем надо - переключает фокус на следующий инпут.

(!) UPD → Вероятно через `slice()` можно было и вовсе на одном инпуте всё организовать и куда проще. Просто я как начал на 4-х, так и довел до конца.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/zuqekjsy/)

```js
(function(){

const moo = document.getElementsByClassName('moo');
//сразу ставим фокус при клике на div id="focus". 
//click можно заменить на mouseenter и смотреть что там получается
document.getElementById('focus').addEventListener('click',function(){
  const L0 = moo[0].value.length;
  const L1 = moo[1].value.length;
  const L2 = moo[2].value.length;
  const L3 = moo[3].value.length;
  //проверяем, если везде всё заполнено - возвращаемся и ничего не трогаем
  if( L0 == 3 && L1 == 3 && L2 == 2 && L3 == 2 ) {return;}
  //если оно не вернулось и всё еще тут - проверит остальные варианты заполнения
  //(на случай, если пользователь заполнил не всё. Чтобы всегда фокус не ставился на первом)
       if( L0 < 3 ) { moo[0].focus(); }
  else if( L0 == 3 && L1 < 3) { moo[1].focus(); }
  else if( L0 == 3 && L1 == 3 && L2 < 2) { moo[2].focus(); }
  else if( L0 == 3 && L1 == 3 && L2 == 2) { moo[3].focus(); }
});//Символ && означает "и" = одновременное выполнение нескольких условий

//Само переключение фокуса при вводе
for(let i = 0; i < moo.length; i++){
  moo[i].addEventListener('input', function(){
    //для этого в HTML добавил data-num=".." чтобы здесь получить это число
    //и не добавлять лишних условий. Условие i < 3, чтобы не было ошибки
    if( i < 3 && this.value.length == Number( this.dataset.num ) ){
      moo[(i+1)].focus();
    }
    //на последнем инпуте не переключение фокуса нужно, а запрет...
    //Если введенное число оказалось 3-м, режем введенное через slice()
    //оставляя только первые 2 символа
    if( moo[3].value.length > 2 ){
      moo[3].value = moo[3].value.slice(0,2);
    }
  });
  
  //keyup дает возможность определить нажатую кнопку.
  //если внутри текущего инпута пусто, а был нажат b-space, переключаем фокус
  moo[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    if( e.key.match(/Backspace/ig) && this.value.length == 0 && i > 0) {
        moo[(i-1)].focus();
    }
  });
}

})();
```

```css
.black {font-size:20px;display:inline-block;}
.orange {border-bottom: 2px solid orange;display:inline-block;}
.moo {
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  width: 30px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="focus">
  <div class="black">+7 ( </div>
  <div class="orange">
    <input class="moo" data-num="3" placeholder="* * *">
  </div>
  <div class="black"> ) </div>
  <div class="orange">
    <input class="moo" data-num="3" placeholder="* * *"> - 
    <input class="moo" data-num="2" placeholder="* *"> - 
    <input class="moo" data-num="2" placeholder="* *">
  </div>
</div>
```

Немного поигрался... Mouseenter выглядит лучше, чем click. Но он позволяет в одном инпуте напечатать больше символов чем надо. Задолбался условия добавлять и оставил это дело вам)) [например покрасить число в красный, если оно оказалось длиннее чем надо]